# NullReferenceException in Length

Tags: c#, linq

I have a code:

```
string[] sizes = new string[] {"1","11","2","22","200","222", null, "105", "101", "102", "103", "90" };

try
{
  var size = from x in sizes
           orderby x.Length, x
           select x;

  foreach (var p in size)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(p);
  }
   Console.Read();
}
catch (NullReferenceException)
{
}
```

How can i catch null in x.Length, and continue to execute code??

Comment: how about "where x is not null" clause or something like that?

Comment: You won't b be able to catch the exception and continue from where you were (you shouldn't anyway). Stack unwinding will have happened and you won't have the scoped variables between the try and catch. Do as others say and avoid it by checking for null.

Comment: check the solution tha will work fo ryou...

Answer (score 11):

> How can i catch null in x.Lenght, and continue to execute code??

Well, what do you want the value to be in this case? For example, you could use:

```
orderby x == null ? -1 : x.Length, x
```

Or possibly:

```
orderby x == null ? int.MaxValue : x.Length, x
```

Or possibly:

```
orderby x == (x ?? "").Length, x
```

Or maybe you should filter the string to start with:

```
var size = from x in sizes
           where x != null
           orderby x.Length, x
           select x;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to add

```
where x != null
```

in your filtering